# lower versus length syntax in python?

Tags: python, string

I'm new to Python and I have a question about the string operations. Is there an over-arching reason that I should understand as to why the lower operation is written as 'variable.lower()' while another one, say length, would be written as 'len(variable)'?

Comment: `.lower` converts the string to lowercase... when you want a string in lowercase, I recommend using `.lower`. When you want the length, I recommend `len`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**lower** is a string method, that is, a function built in to the string object itself. It only applies to string objects.

**len** is a built in function, that is, a function available in the top namespace. It can be called on many different objects (strings, lists, dicts) and isn't unique to strings.